# Issue with mysql fetch array

Tags: php

I am using below code to loop records and display the Country value. If there are duplicate values they are all listed like Australia, Australia, United States, United States, United States. How can I remove any duplicates and just show Australia, United States? I cant use DISTINCT in mysql_query as I need to use an existing mysql_query.  Thanks

```
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   echo $row['Country'];
}

?>
```

I cant use DISTINCT in mysql_query as I need to use an existing mysql_query.

I am using

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM specials WHERE expiry > CURDATE() ORDER BY Country;") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Do you have duplicate values in your database?

Comment: Use the DISTINCT in your fetching query, to extract each record only once!

Comment: In your query where you are selecting country use Distinct(country) then no duplicate will get.

Comment: Yes I have duplicates in db

Comment: I cant use DISTINCT in mysql_query as I need to use an existing mysql_query.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this would be to use [`DISTINCT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/distinct-optimization.html) clause in your MySQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM table_name
```

But however, since you added this:

> I cant use DISTINCT in mysql_query as I need to use an existing mysql_query.

You can simply store all the countries in an array and then use PHP's built-in function [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/array_unique) to remove the duplicate values, like so:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $countries[] = trim( $row['Country'] );
}
$countries = array_unique($countries);
```

Comment: Amal is on the right track with the distinct qualifier. To complete this, you will need to group by, otherwise you will be missing information. @user1823053, I assume you will be summing some value to get all the information for the country considered.

Comment: Thanks as you can probably figure I am very new to this - how do i then show the result on the page?

Comment: @user1823053: `foreach($countries as $country) { echo $country; }` -- that should do it, but note that it's not a very good approach. See crafter's comment above.